# Vertically aligning images in magnific popup

Tags: html, css, magnific-popup

I am trying to align my images in the web page's gallery vertically so all the bottoms match up on one line? I am using magnific popup. How can I do this? Currently they are centered vertically like so:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to this or a demo? It's hard to diagnose without knowing how these images are being positioned.

Comment: http://codepen.io/collection/nLcqo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for help with HTML and CSS you should post what you have tried so far or something else otherwise. In any case I'm going to assume you want a HTML/CSS based answer and make a suggestion to use flex box layout like so:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
```

Flexbox isn't supported in IE9 or earlier so be careful about that.

Alternatively, you could add `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: bottom` to the images (divs in the example)

```css
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
```